# Samba software installation

Tags: software-installation, samba

If the Samba Icon is not visible using the DASH resource search icon does it mean that the installation failed?  I cannot get the file-sharing function working and I believe it is due to an incomplete installation of Samba.

Answer (score 1):

*system-config-samba* is a graphical user interface for creating, modifying, and deleting samba shares and users. To install system-config-samba open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install system-config-samba
```

The system-config-samba icon does not appear in the Dash. To start system-config-samba from the terminal type:

```
sudo system-config-samba
```

Smb4K is an advanced network neighborhood browser and Samba share mounting utility for the KDE Software Compilation. It scans your network neighborhood for all available workgroups, servers and shares and can mount all desired shares to your local file system. Smb4K utilizes the programs of the Samba software suite. Its purpose is to provide a program that is easy to use and has as many features as possible. To install Smb4K (optional) open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install smb4k
```

Smb4k can be launched by clicking its icon in the Dash.